# Baseband signal processing algorithms

Tags: algorithms, baseband

What is one exactly referring to when you say "baseband signal processing algorithms"?
Can anyone give a few (common) examples.

Comment: This question is incredibly broad and open-ended, and hence not a great fit for this site. Maybe you can narrow down your question? **Why** are you asking this? What do you (not) understand about *baseband signals*?

Comment: "Baseband" means that the signal has no carrier; in other words, it has not been frequency-shifted. The opposite is "passband algorithms". Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Baseband signal processing algorithms would refer to any algorithm that is written after you have down converted your RF or IF signals to baseband(signal centered around 0 Hz).

Example : Suppose there is a difference in the RF carrier frequency between the transmitter and receiver . So , after downconversion at the receiver , there will be a frequency offset (equal to Tx Center Frequency - Receive Center Frequency) in the baseband signal . In this case , an algorithm to estimate/correct this frequency offset on the baseband signal can be termed as a baseband signal processing algorithm.

Other baseband algorithms could include estimation/correction of Timing Offset and IQ Impairements to name a few.